# If I download Steam on Ubuntu, does that mean I can play any game I get on Steam ON Ubuntu?

Tags: steam, ubuntu

This question may or may not be very stupid, as I am kind of ignorant when it comes to computers. My friend has convinced me to switch to Linux, and I'm trying to figure out how I can game on it.

Comment: Also note that some indie bundles, e.g. https://www.humblebundle.com/, provide Linux and Mac versions of many games.

Comment: An additional note @Zommuter, the Steam keys for most Humble Bundles will mean you can then download the Linux version from Steam. YMMV with what games have their Linux version uploaded to Steam.

Comment: www.lgdb.org and desura are good sources to check into for gaming on Linux.

Answer (score 35):

There is currently a subset of Steam's entire collection available on Linux (viewable on the [Featured Linux Games](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/) page), however Valve is making a concerted push toward Linux as the OS of choice for gaming, meaning that more will follow.

There are two reasons for this push to Linux,

- They believe Microsoft's Windows 8 is a [catastrophe](http://www.kotaku.com.au/2012/07/gabe-newell-wants-to-support-linux-because-windows-8-is-a-catastrophe/)
- They (and a few third party companies) are currently working on a Steam-based console called the [Steam Machine](http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamMachines/), which will come pre-installed with [Steam OS](http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamOS/), a Linux variant (although it won't be locked down to that OS, you'll be able to install anything on it as you please).

As such, whilst it may not look like there are much games on Linux yet, you can expect more to come.

Answer (score 6):

Steam has a limited number of games available on its Linux platform. You can visit the [Steam Linux store](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/) to see which games are available.

Comment: It now also makes the entirety of its library available on linux via wine/proton, albeit with a "may or may not work" non-guarantee. That said, a surprising number of them do work quite well.